# Angular 9 NG Build with Localize

Tags: angular, localization, ng-build

I have `default` locale and `/nl` locale.

I am having an issue with `ng build --prod --localize`. it **says:**

> Locale data for 'en-US' cannot be found.  No locale data will be
>   included for this locale.

But it continues to build, However in `dist/myProject` I have folder `en-US`  and `nl/`

So I upload in the production server in htdocs  folder all contents from `en-US` and `nl` folder

so my final production url is:

**Loads default:**

```
mydomain.com/    redirects to: mydomain.com/dashboard
```

**Loads nl locale:**

```
mydomain.com/nl  redirect to:  mydomain.com/nl/dashboard
```

When I load the first time both work fine but when I refresh the page on both cases it goes blank with 404 on the file:
styles, runtime, polyfills, main which contains the `en-US` path on it.

I am not sure why as before with the previous version this wasn't an issue.

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: I've seen that they now create folder inside root as en-US if you don't specify. Before they didn't create sub-folder for main language...

Comment: @MiroslavMaksimovic yes that's right. I not particularly enjoying this but I have now to run two separate commands to generate for production one for Root folder as in `/` and other for locale as in `nl` **E.G:** `ng build --prod` and upload to server then run  `ng build --prod --localize` and then just upload the locale `nl` folder so now I have a redundant 'en-US' locale which I don't need, unless there is a more productive way which I don't know.

Comment: I agree, that is pain now... @Juliano

Comment: do you have the property: `  "sourceLocale": "en-US", in your angular json under the i18n explicit defined? there it sould create all required files for the default locale. see [the official docs | https://angular.io/guide/i18n#merge-the-completed-translation-file-into-the-app]